# REST API URI design pattern: Non-hierarchical path?

Tags: rest, api

At work we're discussing how to structure our upcoming APIs. As of now, we're about to launch an API containing different user information endpoints, and though we'd publish it under an URI like this: `api.mycompany.com/userinfo`. Examples of endpoints:

- api.mycompany.com/userinfo/users
- api.mycompany.com/userinfo/users/{id}
- api.mycompany.com/userinfo/api-docs  <-- Swagger document for this particular API will be located here

This type of setup would allow us to have server1.mycompany.com host the API, and use our load balancer / proxy to forward traffic to api.mycompany.com/userinfo to server1.mycompany.com. For our next API running on server2.mycompany.com, we'll simply have our load balancer / proxy forward traffic from api.company.com/transportation to server2.mycompany.com, like this:

- api.mycompany.com/transportation/cars
- api.mycompany.com/transportation/cars/{id}
- api.mycompany.com/transportation/api-docs  <-- Swagger document for this particular API will be located here

By using "userinfo" and "transportation" in the URI, we'll have a simple way to reference our different APIs as a whole, and a simple way to publish the Swagger UI along side the actual API.

My concern with these URIs is that they're not hierarchical, but more like a way to group endpoints together. Nor is "userinfo" a resource, so compared to the REST API examples one typically comes across online, using elements such as "userinfo" and "transportation" in the path may not be according to best practices.

Does this design break any REST API design patterns? If so, how would you suggest us publishing our different APIs under a single fqdn (api.mycompany.com)? Or are there reasons not to use a single fqdn for all of our APIs?

Any input will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

REST doesn't care what spellings you use for your URI

> My concern with these URIs is that they're not hierarchical, but more like a way to group endpoints together. Nor is "userinfo" a resource

*Identifiers* being "hierarchical" doesn't (necessarily) promise anything about a hierarchy of *resources*.  The fact that there is a resource identified by `/userinfo/users` does *not* imply that there is also a resource identified by `/userinfo`.  Think Key/Value store, not File System.

A Rails developer might recognize `/userinfo` and `/transportation` as [namespaces](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing).

> If so, how would you suggest us publishing our different APIs under a single fqdn (api.mycompany.com)? Or are there reasons not to use a single fqdn for all of our APIs?

In a [2014 interview](https://www.infoq.com/articles/roy-fielding-on-versioning), Fielding offered this answer about versioning:

> It is always possible for some unexpected reason to come along that requires a completely different API, especially when the semantics of the interface change or security issues require the abandonment of previously deployed software. My point was that there is no need to anticipate such world-breaking changes with a version ID. We have the hostname for that. What you are creating is not a new version of the API, but a new system with a new brand.

If you squint at that, it might imply that different API *should* be on different (logical) hosts.

Answer (score 0):

> Does this design break any REST API design patterns?

Nope. There are no "REST API design patterns". And REST doesn't say anything about what URLs should look like. REST says to treat them as opaque. There's an argument that web API URLs should be "hackable", that is, easily understandable and modifiable by a human. I'd argue that your URL structure is hackable. I'm not aware of any persuasive argument that URLs must be hierarchical in nature.